# Google search suggestion api

Tags: c#, json, google-search-api

I am trying to scrape Google search suggestion using c# but am unable to parse the response which looks like json.

The url I am using is 
`http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&hl=en&gl=us&gs_rn=23&gs_ri=youtube&ds=yt&cp=2&gs_id=d&q=jk`

and here is an  example of response data

```
window.google.ac.h(["jk",[["jk news",0],["jkfilms",0],["jk party",0],["jkt48 kokoro no placard",0],["jkt48 river",0],["jk simmons",0,[3]],["jkn",0],["jkt48",0],["jk rowling",0],["jkt48 fortune cookie",0]],{"q":"M9pm0qoSNfax1agFT10pPSqRq54","j":"d","k":1}])
```

I have tried using json.net and string operations like trim,replace,remove etc without any success
Is there any easy way to get the suggested keywords into an array?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it always starts with `window.google.ac.h(` and ends with `)` then you can just do:

```
var json = input.Replace("window.google.ac.h(", "").TrimEnd(')');
```

Which produces valid JSON according to http://jsonlint.com/, which you can always put into JSON.NET or similar.

<sub>P.S. Scraping this kind of thing may be against Google's ToS, I suggest you read them.</sub>